# CSS: how to implement loading bar animation

Tags: html, css

So I wanted to copy a animated loading bar from here: https://www.cssscript.com/demo/animated-progress-bar-component-with-pure-css/

But my loading bar is not animating.

What's wrong with it?

```css
.loading-bar {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: #EEE;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.loading-bar-animation {
  transition: none 0s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-size: 35px 35px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #aaa;
  -webkit-animation: cssProgressActive 2s linear infinite;
  animation: cssProgressActive 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading-bar">
  <div class="loading-bar-animation">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the animation to the CSS script.

```css
.loading-bar {
     height: 18px;
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 100%;
     font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
     background-color: #EEE;
     box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
 .loading-bar-animation {
     transition: none 0s ease 0s;
     width: 100%;
     height: 18px;
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.125) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.125) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.125) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
     background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.125) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.125) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.125) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
     background-size: 35px 35px;
     box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     background-color: #aaa;
     -webkit-animation: cssProgressActive 2s linear infinite;
     animation: cssProgressActive 2s linear infinite;
}

/* Must Include the animation below */
 @-webkit-keyframes cssProgressActive {
     0% {
         background-position:0 0 
    }
     100% {
         background-position:35px 35px 
    }
}
 @keyframes cssProgressActive {
     0% {
         background-position:0 0 
    }
     100% {
         background-position:35px 35px 
    }
}
 @-webkit-keyframes cssProgressActiveRight {
     0% {
         background-position:0 0 
    }
     100% {
         background-position:-35px -35px 
    }
}
 @keyframes cssProgressActiveRight {
     0% {
         background-position:0 0 
    }
     100% {
         background-position:-35px -35px 
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>CSS Loading Bar</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="loading-bar">
  <div class="loading-bar-animation">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I thought cssProgressActive is predefined animation in CSS. But you have to declare it. That was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your say that `.loading-bar-animation` has the animation `cssProgressActive`. Problem is that you don't define this animation. After research this animation is this one and is normaly defined in the `cssProgress.css` file. Are you sure that you have imported it ?

```css
.loading-bar {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: #EEE;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.loading-bar-animation {
  transition: none 0s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-size: 35px 35px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #aaa;
  -webkit-animation: cssProgressActive 2s linear infinite;
  animation: cssProgressActive 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes cssProgressActive { 
  0% {
    background-position:0 0
  }
  
  100% {
   background-position:35px 35px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading-bar">
  <div class="loading-bar-animation">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't include the CSS and your wrappers are not set properly.
Here how to make it work:

```css
.loading-bar {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: #EEE;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.loading-bar-animation {
  transition: none 0s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-size: 35px 35px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #aaa;
  -webkit-animation: cssProgressActive 2s linear infinite;
  animation: cssProgressActive 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.cssscript.com/demo/animated-progress-bar-component-with-pure-css/assets/css/cssProgress.css">

<div class="cssProgress">
  <div class="progress1">

<div class="loading-bar">
  <div class="loading-bar-animation">
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to copy the animation

```css
@-webkit-keyframes 
cssProgressActive { 0% {
background-position:0 0
}
100% {
background-position:35px 35px
}
}
@keyframes 
cssProgressActive { 0% {
background-position:0 0
}
100% {
background-position:35px 35px
}
}
.loading-bar {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: #EEE;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.loading-bar-animation {
  transition: none 0s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-size: 35px 35px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #aaa;
  -webkit-animation: cssProgressActive 2s linear infinite;
  animation: cssProgressActive 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="cssProgress">
  <div class="progress1">

<div class="loading-bar">
  <div class="loading-bar-animation">
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```